# Is there a term for children whose parents' marriage ends with nullity?

Tags: catholicism, marriage, children, annulment

In its discussion of marriage, the *Catechism of the Catholic Church* (*CCC*) states, "The Church holds the exchange of consent between the spouses to be the indispensable element"(*CCC* **1626**) that seals the covenant of matrimony. "If this freedom is lacking, the marriage is invalid." (*CCC* **1628**)

The *CCC* goes on to say, "For this reason (or for other reasons that render the marriage null and void), the Church ... can declare a nullity of marriage, i.e., that the marriage never existed." (*CCC* **1629**)

In consideration of this, it lends to question what the nature of the sexual relations were if the marriage never existed. However, that's an aside; it's the children of such a union I'm asking about. Presumptively, these are children baptized in the Church with godparents.

**Is there a term for children born from what was thought to be a valid Catholic marriage whose parents then go through legal divorce and the Church delclares the marriage null**? Please no derogatory answers, but if there's something "you've heard somewhere," feel free to add as a comment with some context.

Comment: Answer to your first question https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/53576/did-a-married-couple-live-in-fornication-if-annulled-catholic

Comment: Why does "the Church declare the marriage null" in this situation? And who considered it a valid marriage?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### Yes, there is a term: legitimate children

[Canon 1137 of The Code of Canon Law:](http://www.vatican.va/archive/ENG1104/__P43.HTM)

> “The children conceived or born of a valid or putative marriage are
>   legitimate.”

[Canon 1061 of the Code of Canon Law](http://www.vatican.va/archive/ENG1104/__P3V.HTM)

> “An invalid marriage is called putative if it has been celebrated in
>   good faith by at least one of the parties, until both parties become
>   certain of its nullity”.

There is no stain, and no fault, laid upon any child under canon law due to a decree of nullity.

Beyond that simple term, based on your presumption

> Presumptively, these are children baptized in the Church with godparents.

there is another term for those children:  ***Baptized Catholics.***

Comment: Fair enough, but.I wasn't asking about the legitimacy of the children per se; rather, within the context of a legitimate child and baptism, is there nomenclature associated with the annulment. However, Canon 1137 does fully answer the question of legitimacy. +1

Comment: Please note: you can baptize your children even when you are not married! And you do not need the consent of the other parent. You however must convince the priest that you will raise the child according to catholic beliefs.

Comment: @Tony_KiloPapaMikeGolf That's beyond the scope of the question, but thanks for pointing that out.  That's the "work with your priest" deal rather than the "standard practice" or presumption.

Comment: I suppose you could call them "children of a presumptive marriage", but there's really no need to single them out in that way.

Comment: @MattGutting *really no need to single them out in that way* Yeah, that's right.

Comment: This is not necessarily true. Can. 1061 is speaking of invalid marriage (the children of which are always illegitimate), whereas Can. 1137 is speaking of valid or putatively valid marriages (whose children, as that canon says, are legitimate). Notice that both invalid and valid marriages can be called putative.

Comment: @KorvinStarmast Where does the Church say that children of an invalid marriage can be legitimate?

Comment: A marriage, to be declared invalid, is an after the fact declaration. *1060 Marriage possesses the favor of law; therefore, in a case of doubt, the validity of a marriage must be upheld until the contrary is proven*   *Can.  1059 Even if only one party is Catholic, the marriage of Catholics is governed not only by divine law but also by canon law, without prejudice to the competence of civil authority concerning the merely civil effects of the same marriage* --  Illegitimacy is a civil effect, not a sacramental effect.

Comment: @Geremia If you want to discuss a child born of a marriage that is defined as illicit due to age, that appears to be a separate question. *Can.  1083 §1. A man before he has completed his sixteenth year of age and a woman before she has completed her fourteenth year of age cannot enter into a valid marriage. §2. The conference of bishops is free to establish a higher age for the licit celebration of marriage*

Comment: @Geremia I appreciate your trying to help, but since we have answers that do not agree, I'll ask you to not edit my answer to be your answer.  I rolled back to my answer, and I'll give it a day or two and then decide on whether or not to edit it.  Having been in the RCIA ministry for some years and this question coming up again and again, and hearing the unequivocal answer from ordained clergy on this matter, I will stand by this answer.   This isn't me making something up: this is how it is held and interpreted.  If you can find a USCCB ruling the disputes this, I am all ears.

Answer (score 2):

The answer to this question depends upon whether the marriage is invalid or valid.

If the marriage is valid (either certainly valid or putatively valid), then the children are legitimate, even if the marriage is subsequently annuled:

> [Canon 1137](http://www.vatican.va/archive/ENG1104/__P43.HTM) The children conceived or born of a valid or putative[ly valid] marriage are legitimate.

Expressed negatively: If "children [are not] conceived or born of a valid or putative[ly valid] marriage," then they are illegitimate.

The canonist Charles Augustine, O.S.B., D.D.—commentating on 1917 Code [canon 1174](https://books.google.com/books?id=2XbtF6Y21LUC&pg=384), which corresponds to the 1983 Code [canon 1137](http://www.vatican.va/archive/ENG1104/__P43.HTM)—writes in his [*A Commentary on the New Code of Canon Law* book 3, vol. 5, p. 332](https://archive.org/stream/1917CodeOfCanonLawCommentary#page/n2241/mode/2up):

> But legitimacy always requires a *marriage*, whether certainly or putatively valid. A marriage is certainly *valid* if contracted without an invalidating impediment and according to the form prescribed by the Church. A *putatively valid marriage* is one contracted with due observance of the prescribed form, but with an invalidating impediment, the existence of which is unknown to one of the parties.

The [*New Commentary on the Code of Canon Law* p. 1259](https://books.google.com/books?id=JKgZEjvB5cEC&pg=1259), published in 2000, also describes how "putative marriage" in [Canon 1137](http://www.vatican.va/archive/ENG1104/__P43.HTM) specifically means a "putatively valid marriage":

> For a marriage to be considered putative, it must have been celebrated according to the required form and, therefore, have the appearance of a marriage. Thus, when a Catholic enters marriage without observing the canonical form and without being dispensed from its observance, the attempted marriage is not considered putative but simply invalid. If, however, the canonical form was observed but was substantially defective (e.g., the official minister was not properly delegated), the marriage would be considered putative.
>
> The most significant effect of a putative marriage is that any children born of it are considered legitimate, even if it is subsequently declared invalid (c. 1137). A putative marriage also enjoys the favor of the law. It remains putative until both spouses become certain of its nullity. Thus, the spouses' doubts, even grave doubts, about the validity of their marriage are not sufficient to deprive it of its status as putative. The spouses on their own may become certain of the invalidity of their marriage because of an impediment. However, most couples become certain that their marriage was invalid because of a defect of consent only through the decision of a church tribunal.

Comment: This doesn't seem to correspond to the canon definition of "putative marriage" in the current code, canon 1061 section 3: "An invalid marriage is called putative if at least one party celebrated it in good faith". It says nothing about a requirement of canonical form (which seems reasonable, since the Church appears to consider marriages made between two non-Catholics as valid).

Comment: @MattGutting 1983 Can. 1061 §3 is verbatim the same as [1917 Can. 1015 §4](https://books.google.com/books?id=2XbtF6Y21LUC&pg=353). It speaks of when an invalid marriage can be called putative. It says nothing about how a valid marriage can be called putative. (Putative does not mean doubtful; it speaks of a precisely determinate situation.)

Comment: I'm not stating that it does say anything like that. I'm saying that if an invalid marriage is a putative marriage (and the canon does not appear to require invalid marriages to be celebrated according to canonical form in order to be putative marriages), then the children born are legitimate, contrary to your statement that "if the marriage is invalid, the children are illegitimate".

Comment: @MattGutting Children born of invalid marriages are illegitimate. This is the definition of illegitimacy. Putatively or certainly invalid marriages are still invalid (i.e., they're not marriages).

Comment: But if invalid marriages can be putative marriages (as you seem to admit by your first comment), and the children of putative marriages are always legitimate (by canon 1137), then it would seem that the children of at least some invalid marriages are indeed legitimate.

Comment: @MattGutting Canonist Charles Augustine, O.S.B., D.D, commentating on 1917 Code canon 1174 (cf. 1983 Code canon 1137) interprets "putative marriage" there as "putatively valid marriage." The purpose of that canon, as he explains, is to protect the children in the case there are invalidating impediments unknown to the parents. You are interpreting "putative marriage" in that canon as meaning "putatively valid marriage" or "putatively invalid marriage" indifferently.

Comment: @MattGutting See the quote from the [_New Commentary on the Code of Canon Law_](https://books.google.com/books?id=JKgZEjvB5cEC&pg=1259) that I've added to my answer. It explains what a putative marriage is.

Comment: The New Commentary on the Code of Canon Law p. 1259, published in 2000 supports my answer.  Thanks for doing the research for me. :)  As to your assertion: *If the marriage is invalid, then the children are illegitimate. This is the definition of illegitimacy*  That is _your_ definition.   You seem to be confusing *licit* with *valid* here.

Comment: FWIW, I suspect that 100 years ago the way your have presented the answer would be more likely to be what is taught.

Comment: @KorvinStarmast How do you, canon law, or the Church define legitimacy, then?

Comment: @Geremia I imagine that depends upon what country and culture you live in.  That matter, legitimacy or otherwise, lies in the civil realm of things like inhereitance, rights, etc.  (That's the short version of how our clergy instructed us). Look, I am a huge proponent of people taking marriage seriously, of the sacramental nature of marriage seriously, and of welcoming children into the world and sacrificing for them.  Marriage matters a lot, far more than how civil society treats it as disposable.  What we were taught to teach is that any defect is among the adults, not their offspring.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/63234/discussion-between-geremia-and-korvinstarmast).

Answer (score 1):

This is what I heard on Relevant Radio a few years back.  I believe it was Fr. Rocky who said something to this effect: There is no special status for the children as the Church presumes that the man and woman entered into a marriage that was later found to be null did so in good faith.  I found the reasoning to be pretty confusing.  But I believe it had something to do with the marriage appearing to be valid and giving the parents the benefit of the doubt, that the fact they parents *thought* they were married, it makes it so their children are not illegitimate.

Comment: Peter, marriage accrues the favor of law: it is presumed valid unless challenged and found wanting.  See my answer.  You may want to keep that in your hip pocket when interacting with kids and parents in your ministry to youth.  Know the facts; know the church's unambiguous position.

Comment: @korvin that's a good point - very important not to bandy about half-heard truths in Religious Ed.

Comment: It doesn't matter what the parents think but what the Church thinks.

Comment: @Geremia I'm not even sure it matters what the Church thinks, but what the Holy Spirit thinks.   The Church discerns what that is and the rest of us do our best.